# Search data in first field first, if not then next field, if not then third field

Tags: php, mysql

I have to find out data from db using mysql query.

screenio is:-
  I have to search data according to state. In admin, i store three state for each record. So when ever user search, query will search in first field. if data not find then second and if not then third field.

Is it possible to do it in one query so i am able to do pagination.

Comment: You can use If/else statements in SQL. Take a look over here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: Can you post the table designs you want to query? Or is just using `foo` and `bar` ok in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is you can write your query by comparing all of your three columns and order the result set according to the matched ones

```
select * ,
case 
   when  col1 = 'some value' then 3
   when  col2 = 'some value' then 2
   when  col2 = 'some value' then 1
else 0 end as matching_criteria
from table
where col1 = 'some value'
or col2 ='some value'
or col3 ='some value'
having matching_criteria > 0
order by matching_criteria desc
limit 10
```

Now if `col1` matches some value then it will be shown first in the result set if not then it will be at the end of result same for other columns other approach is to query with column one and check results if empty then go for second column and so on